# Static IP on raspberry and Networking

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, dhcp

I'm quite new to this world and I do not have a lot of experience with raspberry PI nor with networking, and I have a doubt:

I am supposed to set a static IP to a raspberry device: ok, easy, lots of tutorials out there. The purpose is: Access a site that is on the rasp, via a network (no internet needed), like you do with your router when you configure it.

HOWEVER, this raspberry will be sent to many different places (imagine it's like a group of friends, each week it will be at one's house. They do not know how to program or set things up or even access the rasp). Therefore.. different networks.

The doubt is: Would a static IP still work in that case? Or is it restrained to one's network DHCP?

If it does not work, any ideas on how can I make it work? I'd like to access a html file hosted on the raspberry, but as its IP changes and suppose I don't know what it is, how can I access this html from my computer, both being connected on the same network?

Answer (score 0):

A static IP is restricted to one network, which means you can just simply set a static IP on each network via the Router-Settings. Or configure it your self with a Bash Script.

A more dynamic way would be to just use the hostname, which leads to an access like this http://yourHostname/yourFile.html than even with a different IP everything is working. This assumes that you're webserver is right configured.
For example an Apache2-Conf with VirtualHost could look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName yourHostname
<VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a more dynamic solution and avoid using a static IP address, because you don't know which subnets are used in different places. For example a wifi might use `192.168.0.xxx`, another one might use `192.168.1.xxx` and so on...

**Solution:** try to use a `hostname` for your Rpi. You will then access it by using its name and not its IP.

- step 1: try to find how to setup your `hostname`
- step 2: you will have to somehow "populate" this `hostname` to the network. Some use the `avahi-daemon` for this.
- step 3: you might need to install `Bonjour` to your laptop

More info:

- about `avahi` here: [Raspberry Pi not reachable via its hostname in LAN](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7640/raspberry-pi-not-reachable-via-its-hostname-in-lan)
- about `Bonjour` here: 
  [Accessing Raspberry Web server with a ".local" address?](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=56191)